# Python Pandas Dataframe Replace NaN with values from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace my column with NaN

```
group_choices = ['Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3']

Groups limit
1 NaN NaN
2 Group1 2
3 Group2 2
4 Group3 2
5 NaN NaN
6 NaN NaN
7 NaN NaN
```

How can I replace NaN, randomly based on the group_choises?

I'm also trying to limit how often a group_choise can be randomised selected because of the limit value in the limit column.

I'm trying to get this result:

```
Groups limit
1 Group3 NaN
2 Group1 2
3 Group2 2
4 Group3 2
5 Group1 NaN
6 Group2 NaN
7 Out of groups
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `fillna` with dictionaries

```
dct = dict(zip(df.Groups.loc[pd.isna].index, group_choices))

df.fillna({'Groups': dct}).fillna({'Groups': 'Out of groups'})

          Groups  limit
1         Group1    NaN
2         Group1    2.0
3         Group2    2.0
4         Group3    2.0
5         Group2    NaN
6         Group3    NaN
7  Out of groups    NaN
```

---

### Old Answers

Useful but I like the new one better.  It illustrates the evolution of my thought process.

#### Generators

```
def get_some(i, n):
  for x in [*i] * n:
    yield x

def fill(s, i, n):
  gs = get_some(i, n)
  for x in s:
    if pd.isnull(x):
      try:
        yield next(gs)
      except StopIteration:
        yield "Out of groups"
    else:
      yield x

df.assign(Groups=[*fill(df.Groups, group_choices, 1)])

          Groups  limit
1         Group1    NaN
2         Group1    2.0
3         Group2    2.0
4         Group3    2.0
5         Group2    NaN
6         Group3    NaN
7  Out of groups    NaN
```

---

Alternative

```
def get_some(i, n):
  for x in [*i] * n:
    yield x

df.assign(Groups=df.Groups.fillna(
    df.Groups.loc[pd.isna].pipe(
        lambda s: pd.Series(dict(zip(s.index, get_some(group_choices, 1))))
    )
).fillna('Out of groups'))
```

Comment: @S.Hendriks I've updated my post again.  You may like the new version better.

Comment: Wow you are truly amazing, thank you the top one looks sick!